# Have a string value, make it get correct object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I got a `data-attribute` that got a string value, from that I would like to be able to get the specific json object (the value of the string). So something like this.

The example below is the stripped version (enough to make the point across), check this fiddle for full version of what I'm trying to do.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a4x5y2m/1)**

```
<div class="js-carousel" data-conf='{"componentSettings": "CarouselSettings" }'>...</div>
```

or

```
 <div class="js-carousel" data-conf='{"componentSettings": "CarouselConfig.hero" }'>...</div>
```

and I got this json objects that got the settings for my js module (in this case it's Slick carousel)

```
var CarouselSettings = {
  accessibility: false,
  autoplay: true
};

var CarouselConfig = {
  hero: {
    accessibility: false,
    autoplay: true
  },
  product: {
    accessibility: true,
    autoplay: false
  }
};
```

I'm able to have a setting with a string value and to trigger a function.

```
"mediaQuery": "isBase2Medium"
```

and that would trigger a mediaquery control function. So I thought maybe I could have a similar approach to this?

Comment: Well not a specific value, but the whole config, as `CarouselConfig.hero` is a json object itself. @Rajesh

Comment: element.slick is undefined,are you sure it is exists?

Comment: @Rajesh it's not expecting they are just an option, check 
`function getComponent(element) { return element === undefined ?$(elementClass) : $(element);}`, if it's not defined it will go with "default" js-class defined.

Comment: @holi-java, that is not the case, if you remove the settings into `.Slick()` on line 43 it will work, https://jsfiddle.net/8a4x5y2m/2/

Comment: so your problem is {componentSettings:"CarouselSettings"} ,you can get the CarouselSettings variable not a string?

Comment: I'm trying to make so that `{"componentSettings": "CarouselSettings" }` will make `CarouselSettings` to become the actual json object that exist. @holi-java

Comment: I know you can use eval(..) could you remove some code that is not necessary for this problem.the code is too long,I can't known where is important.

Comment: I'v answered your question,please see my answer. is this your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my God,the code is too long,I finally find the point of entry to insert eval(...),You can try this solution by use eval(...):

```
    function applySettings(settings) {
        var componentSettings = settings.componentSettings;
        componentSettings = typeof componentSettings == 'string' ? eval('(' + componentSettings + ')') : componentSettings;
        settings.componentSettings = componentSettings;
        return settings;
    }

    function getSettings($element, settings) {
        settings = settings === undefined ? applySettings($element.data(elementConf)) : settings;
        ....

        return settings;
    }
```

Comment: Yea this works, reason I didn't use `Eval()` was because I read it can be unpredictable. Do you see any problems with it?

Comment: eval() is the simple way do this problem.suppose there is a string `settings.options.debug` if you use eval(..) then the thing is simplest.if you use property accessor way you must split all by notation `.`  into an array and using a loop to get the final value.

Comment: if you have to eval somthing in a top object.e.g: `var top={foo:'bar'}`,your expression is `foo`.you only can you this expression,e.g:`eval('(top.'+expression+')')`.that makes the code readable too,but  for maintain not friendly.

Comment: may be using regex together will make the code more readable.

e.g:`eval("(top['%name'])".replace(/%name/,expression))`

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle to do what (I think) you want to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/8a4x5y2m/3/

Please note the following changes I made:

1. The major change is in the `getSettings()` function. There I introduced a check to see if one particular setting (`componentSettings`) is declared as an object in the window (global) scope, and if it does, then it replaces the string parameter with the object. Which brings us to point (2)...
2. You are declaring your configuration objects in global scope using `var`, but in jsFiddle your whole script is put in a `window.onload` handler which makes these variables local to the handler. I removed the `var` keyword to make the parameters global, thus exposing them to the window object, but this is bad practice. Consider putting them either in a global configuration object, and then in the `getSettings()` method above, replace with `window[]` with `myGlobalConf[]`.

Also, please note that I only test the `componentSettings` field. If you want to test every single parameter, then you'll have to iterate over them and do the same check for each.

Comment: I would like to avoid to have them as globals. Also the settings are gone live in their own files, so how does the `myGlobalConf[]` work then?